# Am I allowed to carry shampoo, Oil, etc via India-UK airport after recent hair transplantation?

Tags: air-travel, airports, international-travel, airport-transfer, airport-security

I recently had a hair transplantation in New Delhi, India (1 month ago). Now I need to move to London, UK on work permit.

Am I allowed to carry Shampoo and Oil (4*500ml each=4ltr) all in white, nontransparent plastic bottles via India and UK airports? Or if there are some special cases?

Comment: What kind of oil?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you intend to carry them in the plane as hand luggage, I guess it won't make it as it is beyond the 100 ml limit.

But if you put it in your checked-in luggage, assuming those can't cause fire or damage to the plane, you should be ok. You can check with the airline to be 100% sure.